# How to add explicit type class to attribute in rails? PG::UndefinedFunction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Currently trying to get the sum of all children's specific attributes values while grouped by parents attribute for a chart. For whatever reason, this has stumped me.

In a helper I have:
`YardActivity.group_by_day(:date).joins(:line_transactions).references(:line_transactions).sum(:full_deliver).map(&:to_i)`

Which gives results in a `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist`

I've tried using `pluck` instead of `sum` and I get a very similar error. How do I add a specific type cast? I thought that's what `.map(&:to_i)` was doing?

Edit:

Relevant schema

```
create_table "yard_activities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "account_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.date "date"
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_yard_activities_on_account_id"
end
create_table "line_transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "account_id", null: false
    t.string "full_recieve"
    t.string "full_deliver"
    t.bigint "yard_activity_id", null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_line_transactions_on_account_id"
    t.index ["yard_activity_id"], name: "index_line_transactions_on_yard_activity_id"
  end
```

Desired output

```
{
  Sun, 29 Jul 2018=>193,
  Sun, 05 Aug 2018=>482,
  ..
}
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::Calculations is pretty damn useless in all but the most trivial cases. What you want is probably something like `Parent.group_by_day(:date).joins(:children).select('parents.*', 'SUM(children.child_attribute) AS sum_of_child_attribute')`. If you add your schema and an example of the desired output we can give you a more exact answer.

Comment: You are trying to "sum" a VARCHAR. Did you perhaps mean "COUNT" instead? Or are you storing numbers as Strings for some reason?

Comment: I added the schema and the desired output as well.

Comment: Numbers are being stored as strings after I inherited this project. I didn't want to go through the process of converting the strings to numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Postgres you can typecast columns by using `CAST`:

```
YardActivity.group_by_day(:date)
            .joins(:line_transactions)
            .sum('CAST(line_transactions.full_deliver AS int)')
```

or `::type`

```
YardActivity.group_by_day(:date)
            .joins(:line_transactions)
            .sum('line_transactions.full_deliver::int')
```

But you should really consider beating that legacy database into shape instead of piling more hackyness on top.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Now I'll get to cleaning up the database. Thanks!